# PowerShell - Expand array column in array with repeating rows

Tags: powershell

I have an `System.Array` object called `$Data`, the first ([0]) item looks like this:

```
RecordDate              : {43739, 43740, 43741, 43742...}
MAX_LAST_UPDATE_DATE    : 30/10/2019 14:08:33
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER         : 1000522
EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    : 01/10/2019 00:00:00
EFFECTIVE_END_DATE      : 31/12/4712 00:00:00
CC                      : 0726
REGION_NAME             : Head Office
LOCATION_NAME           : Inventory
FIRST_NAME              : Name
MIDDLE_NAMES            : Mid
LAST_NAME               : Last
KNOWN_AS                : NickName
JOB_TITLE               : Inventory Manager
WORK_NUMBER             : 
Employment Category     : Full Time
NORMAL_HOURS            : 40
GROUP_NAME              : Indirect
Manager Employee Number : 1034422
PERSON_TYPE             : Employee
HIRE_DATE               : 16/11/1983 00:00:00
TERMINATION_DATE        : 
DATE_OF_BIRTH           : 23/05/1966 00:00:00
NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER     : 111
```

I'm trying to kind of unpivot the first column "RecordDate" **on the entire array** like this:

```
RecordDate              : 43739
MAX_LAST_UPDATE_DATE    : 30/10/2019 14:08:33
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER         : 1000522
EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    : 01/10/2019 00:00:00
EFFECTIVE_END_DATE      : 31/12/4712 00:00:00
CC                      : 0726
REGION_NAME             : Head Office
LOCATION_NAME           : Inventory
FIRST_NAME              : Name
MIDDLE_NAMES            : Mid
LAST_NAME               : Last
KNOWN_AS                : NickName
JOB_TITLE               : Inventory Manager
WORK_NUMBER             : 
Employment Category     : Full Time
NORMAL_HOURS            : 40
GROUP_NAME              : Indirect
Manager Employee Number : 1034422
PERSON_TYPE             : Employee
HIRE_DATE               : 16/11/1983 00:00:00
TERMINATION_DATE        : 
DATE_OF_BIRTH           : 23/05/1966 00:00:00
NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER     : 111

RecordDate              : 43740
MAX_LAST_UPDATE_DATE    : 30/10/2019 14:08:33
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER         : 1000522
EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    : 01/10/2019 00:00:00
EFFECTIVE_END_DATE      : 31/12/4712 00:00:00
CC                      : 0726
REGION_NAME             : Head Office
LOCATION_NAME           : Inventory
FIRST_NAME              : Name
MIDDLE_NAMES            : Mid
LAST_NAME               : Last
KNOWN_AS                : NickName
JOB_TITLE               : Inventory Manager
WORK_NUMBER             : 
Employment Category     : Full Time
NORMAL_HOURS            : 40
GROUP_NAME              : Indirect
Manager Employee Number : 1034422
PERSON_TYPE             : Employee
HIRE_DATE               : 16/11/1983 00:00:00
TERMINATION_DATE        : 
DATE_OF_BIRTH           : 23/05/1966 00:00:00
NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER     : 111

RecordDate              : 43741
MAX_LAST_UPDATE_DATE    : 30/10/2019 14:08:33
...
```

**Is there a way to do that with some sneaky `Select -expandproperty` or do the opposite of what `Group-Object` is capable of; without doing combination of `for($i)` and `for($j)` loops?**

It's quite simple on a Table in in Excel PowerQuery, as you just click Expand and voilà.

Regards, Jarek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` with the common `-PipelineVariable` parameter and cloning (PSv3+ syntax):

#### For input collections of `[pscustomobject]` or `[hashtable]` instances:

```
# Sample input array of custom objects to expand by .RecordDate
$array =
  [pscustomobject] @{ RecordDate = 1, 2; OtherProp1 = 'one'; OtherProp2 = 'two' },
  [pscustomobject] @{ RecordDate = 3, 4; OtherProp1 = 'three'; OtherProp2 = 'four' }

# Write the array elements to the pipeline, and store each in variable
# $objectOrHashtable for use in a later pipeline segment.
Write-Output $array -PipelineVariable objectOrHashtable |
  # Expand the input object's .RecordData property, i.e. send its
  # elements one by one to the next pipeline segment.
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty RecordDate | 
    ForEach-Object {
      # Clone the original input object.
      $clone = if ($objectOrHashtable -is [Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
        $objectOrHashtable.psobject.Copy()
      } else { # assume [hashtable] or a type that implements [System.ICloneable]
        $objectOrHashtable.Clone()
      }
      # Assign the record date at hand to the clone...
      $clone.RecordDate = $_
      # ... and output it.
      $clone
    }
```

The above yields the following; note that 4 objects were output, based on enumerating the elements of the input objects' `.RecordDate` array while retaining all other properties:

```
RecordDate OtherProp1 OtherProp2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 one        two
         2 one        two
         3 three      four
         4 three      four
```

Note:

- The above works with two types of input object:

  - *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances, such as created by `Import-Csv`)

    - Note: For technical reasons you cannot use `-is [pscustomobject]` and must instead use the full type name, `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` (the `System.` prefix can be omitted); `[pscustomobject]`, for historical reasons, is the same as `[psobject]` (`System.Management.Automation.PSObject`), and `-is [psobject]` is also true for objects that *aren't* custom objects.
  - *hashtables* (`System.Collections.Hashtable` instances - but not `[ordered]` hashtables); more generally, any type that implements `System.ICloneable`.
- The cloning that is performed on custom objects and hashtable is *shallow* (member-wise), but with scalar string and numeric values that is sufficient.

  - Generally, the `ICloneable` interface doesn't prescribe the specifics of the cloning behavior, which is why its use is generally discouraged.

---

#### For input collections of `[System.Data.DataRow]` instances:

Cloning a collection of `System.Data.DataRow` instances - the rows of data table, `System.Data.DataTable` - **requires *custom* cloning logic**, but the approach and structure of the output are fundamentally the same:

```
# Create a sample DataTable...
$dt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new('sample')
# ... define the columns ...
$dt.Columns.AddRange([System.Data.DataColumn[]] (
  @{ ColumnName = 'RecordDate'; DataType = [object[]] },
  @{ ColumnName = 'OtherProp1'; DataType = [string] },
  @{ ColumnName = 'OtherProp2'; DataType = [string] }
))
# ...and add sample rows.
@{ RecordDate = 1, 2; OtherProp1 = 'one'; OtherProp2 = 'two' },
@{ RecordDate = 3, 4; OtherProp1 = 'three'; OtherProp2 = 'four' } | % {
  $dt.Rows.Add(($dr = $dt.NewRow()))
  foreach ($entry in $_.GetEnumerator()) {
    $dr[$entry.Key] = $entry.Value 
  }  
}

# Create an auxiliary, empty clone of the input data table
# to facilitate cloning of individual rows.
$dtAux = $dt.Clone()

# Write the data rows to the pipeline, and store each in variable
# $obj for use in a later pipeline segment.
Write-Output $dt.Rows -PipelineVariable row |
  # Expand the input object's .RecordData property, i.e. send its
  # elements one by one to the next pipeline segment.
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty RecordDate |
    ForEach-Object {
      # Clone the data row at hand.
      $dtAux.Clear(); $dtAux.ImportRow($row)
      $clone = $dtAux.Rows[0]
      # Assign the record date at hand to the clone...
      $clone.RecordDate = @($_)
      # ... and output it.
      $clone
    }
```